# Excel VBA change value

Tags: excel, vba, replace

I have Excel sheet where is phone numbers at international format (00358xxxxxxx)

and I need to replace that 00358 with 0

I manage to remove that 00358 but I lost leading 0 from phone number.

All cells are text-type

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:B").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "@"

```
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim fnd As Variant
Dim rplc As Variant

fnd = "00358"
rplc = "0"

For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
sht.Cells.Replace what:=fnd, Replacement:=rplc, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
    SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
Next sht
```

Comment: You add ' to the front e.g. rplc = "'0"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use:

```
rplc = "'0"
```

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks guys, it was so easy now :-)